# Is it possible for an IBM mq queue manager at version 7.5+ to send messages to a Websphere mq at version 7.0?

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm looking at upgrading one end of two connected Websphere mq v7.0.1.0 queue managers to the latest version (v9.2 at time of writing). Is there any way to connect the two queue managers at different versions i.e. 7.0.1.0 <=> 9.2?

Initial investigation would suggest only v7.5+ queue managers can communicate with different versions. Are there alternative routes to making this work?

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/mq-7x-80-90-91-and-92-compatibility-previous-versions-including-usage-ccdt-files-jms-bindings-ssltls

Comment: @shashi Hi, thanks for pointing me at this. I had seen this page and I saw the statement regarding compatiblity: "MQ 7.x, 8.0, 9.0, 9.1 and 9.2 queue managers and clients inter operate with queue managers and clients from any previous level of the WebSphere MQ or IBM MQ products." However, none of the following statements seem to explicitly talk about queue manager to queue manager communication. Can you point to any specific documentation which confirms queue manager to queue manager compatibility?

Comment: The statement "MQ 7.x, 8.0, 9.0, 9.1 and 9.2 queue managers and clients inter operate with queue managers and clients from any previous level of the WebSphere MQ or IBM MQ products." covers qmgr-qmgr communication too. Take it from a previous MQ developer. any-to-any qmgr-qmgr communication was designed in from day 1.

Comment: @MoragHughson Thanks Morag, I appreciate the authoritative answer! Do you know if it's possible for me to spin up older versions of Websphere mq for testing purposes (specifically 7.0.1.0)?

Comment: If you have the install images and a compatible O/S then no reason why you can't. Presumably the reason you need to test this is because you have these versions of MQ in your environment, otherwise why would you care? In which case, I would assume you'll have a means to install them.